# Spark SQL first and last aggregated functions -- Unexpected Result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Getting unexpected result while performing first and last aggregated functions on Spark Dataframe.

I have a spark dataframe having columns colA,colB,colC,colD,colE,extraCol1,extraCol2

And I need to do aggregation on this dataframe by

grouping -> colA & colB,max -> colC,max -> colD,first -> colE, extraCol1, extraCol2

So below is dataframe (df) I am using and I am using spark partitioning (3)

```
colA    colB    colC    colD    colE    extraCol1   extracol2
Harshit 23        43    44         A           q    z
Mohit   24        56    62         B           w    x
Harshit 23        32    44         C           e    c
Kali    10        20    460        D           r    v
Aman    20        30    180        E           t    b
Ram     30        100   270        F          yu    n
Kali    10        600   360        G          io    m
Kali    10        600   460        k           p    o
```

Below is code of scala and spark which I am using to perform groupBy operation

```
 val cols = List("colA","colB")

 var  aggFuncSeq = List(max(`colC`) as colC_new, max(`colD`) as colD_new, first(`colE`,true) as colE, first(`extracol2`,true) as extracol2, first(`extraCol1`,true) as extraCol1)

 var aggFuncs = aggFuncSeq.map(e => expr(e))

 df = df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(aggFuncs.head, aggFuncs.tail: _*)

 df.show(10)
```

After performing I am getting unexpected result as below.

```
colA    colB    colC_new    colD_new    colE    extracol2   extraCol1
Harshit     23      43            44        C       c       e
Aman        20      30            180       E       b       t
Kali        10      600           460       D       v       r
Ram         30      100           270       F       n       yu
Mohit       24      56            62        B       x       w
```

But as per the grouping condition and aggregation operation performed, the output result should have first row corresponding to Harshit, for colE, extracol2,  extracol1

So, the expected result was as below

```
colA    colB    colC_new    colD_new    colE    extracol2   extraCol1
Harshit     23      43            44        A       q       z
Aman        20      30            180       E       b       t
Kali        10      600           460       D       v       r
Ram         30      100           270       F       n       yu
Mohit       24      56            62        B       x       w
```

But I am not able to understand this SQL concept, that how it is possible. So, if anybody can help me to figure out this weird problem.

Is it because of partitioning?

How it is giving this result and how to fix it as expected result?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: First is window function , until you order by it wont give you the result as expected .You need to do something like Window.partitionBy(colA,colB).orderBy(colE))

Comment: @sp_user123 Then I can do max(colE) also , it will give me same result. But I want to get first or last column as per the input dataframe provided by user

Comment: orderby(colE) is just an example , in your case i think you need to order by with the same key as group coulmns (desc or asc )

Comment: You might want to add a column `F.monotonically_increasing_id` before doing any shuffling

Comment: @TarunKhaneja Please checkout options below and don't forget to accept an answer if one fits your needs/questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you `groupBy` in Spark, you may change the order of your DataFrame. But not always (eg. if your data is contained on a single worker, it won't change). Hence, just to make sure and to have a scalable solution, you need to re-order in your window function.

In this case, try this:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"key").orderBy($"value")
df
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number.over(w))
  .where($"row_number" === 1)
  .drop("row_number")
```

This selects only the first row, filtered on the `row_number` with `row_number` defined as the index of the row after ordering. This is dropped afterwards because it becomes useless.

*Remark: you may replace* `$` *operators with* `col` *operators. It is only a shortcut for a more concise code.*

Comment: Just updated my answer, please let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{max, _}
    import spark.implicits._

    val columnsDF = Seq(
      ("Harshit", 23, 43, 44, "A", "q", "z"),
      ("Mohit", 24, 56, 62, "B", "w", "x"),
      ("Harshit", 23, 32, 44, "C", "e", "c"),
      ("Kali", 10, 20, 460, "D", "r", "v"),
      ("Aman", 20, 30, 180, "E", "t", "b"),
      ("Ram", 30, 100, 270, "F", "yu", "n"),
      ("Kali", 10, 600, 360, "G", "io", "m"),
      ("Kali", 10, 600, 460, "k", "p", "o")
    ).toDF("ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD", "ColE", "extraCol1", "extraCol2")


    println("Before Aggregation")
    columnsDF.show()

    val cols = List("colA", "colB")

    println("After Aggregation")
    val aggSeqFunction = columnsDF.agg(max(columnsDF.columns(2)),
      max(columnsDF.columns(3)),
      first(columnsDF.columns(4)),
      first(columnsDF.columns(6)),
      first(columnsDF.columns(5)))

    val aggFunction = aggSeqFunction.columns.map(en => expr(en))


    columnsDF.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(aggFunction.head, aggFunction.tail: _*).show()

    /*
            +-------+----+---------+---------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
            |   colA|colB|max(ColC)|max(ColD)|first(ColE, false)|first(extraCol2, false)|first(extraCol1, false)|
            +-------+----+---------+---------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
            |Harshit|  23|       43|       44|                 A|                      z|                      q|
            |   Aman|  20|       30|      180|                 E|                      b|                      t|
            |   Kali|  10|      600|      460|                 D|                      v|                      r|
            |    Ram|  30|      100|      270|                 F|                      n|                     yu|
            |  Mohit|  24|       56|       62|                 B|                      x|                      w|
            +-------+----+---------+---------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
     */
```

I am able to derive the expected result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not because it works on your machine that this option is scalable on a cluster. After a `groupBy` you have no guarantees your `DataFrame` will remain sorted.